# How to show data in a table dynamically when the data is searched and written in the file

Tags: php, html, dynamic

I made e search screen which will search wines according to user filter. Then I made Post/redirect/get pattern to avoid refresh problem. In this the search results written in the redirect file. I'm trying to show those data in a table format, but I can't figure it out what to do. Please someone help. This is the part of the code:

```
$searchResult .= "Wine Name: $wName, V: $variety, Y: $year, WN: $wineryName, R: $Region, C: $cost, S: $stock, O: $ordered<br />";
          $file ="results.php";
          file_put_contents($file, $searchResult);
          header("Location: results.php".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: I assume you want to replace the `<tr>`s with the new rows you get back from the filter?

Comment: You can use a delimiter in your string and then build the table tags from it with simple string replace. Still, you need to explain better what you want to do.

Comment: The result.php is totally blank. It just write the results in the result.php page. but i want to write the result as a table format so that it shows the result in a table.  So for example the result look like this               Wine Name: Titshall, V: Cabernet, Y: 1984, WN: Anderson Daze Vineyard, R: Margaret River, C: 14.51, S: 868, O: 1
Wine Name: Titshall, V: Shiraz, Y: 1984, WN: Anderson Daze Vineyard, R: Margaret River, C: 14.51, S: 868, O: 1
Wine Name: Titshall, V: Riesling, Y: 1977, WN: Binns Group, R: Lower Hunter Valley, C: 8.45, S: 964, O: 2